# Rounding away from zero

Tags: c#

I noticed a very weird behaviour of [Math.Round(double,int,MidpointRounding)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5898377(v=vs.110).aspx) function.

```
System.Math.Round(177777.385,2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)== 177777.39
System.Math.Round(17777.385,2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) == 17777.38
System.Math.Round(1777.385,2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) == 1777.39
```

I tested decimal as well and those are results:

```
System.Math.Round((decimal)177777.385,2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)== 177777.39
System.Math.Round((decimal)17777.385,2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) == 17777.39
System.Math.Round((decimal)1777.385,2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) == 1777.39
```

From all those I would expect X.39 (as this would be the result from AwayFromZero rounding) but rounding **17777.385** seems not to be working.

Could someone explain why this is happening? 
I suspect this has something to do with their binary representation but I am not sure.

I am using Visual C# Interactive Compiler version 2.8.0.62830

Comment: You expect `177777.38` ?

Comment: @CoolJK I've added the explanation

Comment: [Some documentation](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) with a link to a DoubleConverter class that shown the real value of a double

Comment: @MarcoSalerno yes, this is a duplicate. Sorry for that. I voted to close it as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, 17777.385 * 100 (rounding to a specified number of digits first multiplies by 10<sup>digits</sup> and then rounds) would be exactly 1777738.49999999976716935634613037109375, which as you can see is not halfway and so not affected by the halfway rounding flags. This is not due to the multiplication, the input value was already 17777.38499999999839928932487964630126953125.

In 177777.385 * 100, the input was actually some funny number as well, but the multiplication by 100 just happens to result in *exactly* 17777738.5 which is affected by the halfway rounding flag.

Comment: Just to add to the answer, you can see the difference `Round` for `decimal`and `double` in referencesource. [decimal](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs,529d477ad9ffe7c2) and [double](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,f0afe85387e48317)